# Extract a number from a string using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a series of records with ids assigned to them. I.e.

> record1, record2, record3 etc

I'm trying to get the id of the link being clicked using:-

```
$("a.removeTier").live('click', function() {
    var tier = $(this).attr('id').match('/\d+$/');
    alert(tier);
});
```

The variable tier, should only contain the numeric value within the string. Currently, I'm getting null.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just use [*slice()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) or [*substring()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)?

```
 var tier = this.id.slice(6);
 // -> 1, 2, 3... 11... 123, etc
```

Example -  **http://jsfiddle.net/TmBQ8/**

PS, you're getting null at the moment because you're passing a string argument to match, instead of a regular  expression.  Remove the quotes, e.g. `match(/\d+$/)`. Also note in my example, I skipped using a jQuery wrapper and *attr()* since it's the long way around and not as efficient as direct property access.

Answer (score 0):

Using a blunter object:

```
$(this).attr('id').substring("6","7")
```

As noted in comments, this only works for one-digit numbers. So do this instead:

```
$(this).attr('id').replace("record", "")
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work as the number could get very large.

Comment: Of course, you don't know how many digits it will be. In that case, try this. $(this).attr('id').replace("record", "")

Comment: Maybe the downvote was because of the crazy typo in my call to subString.

Comment: @morgancodes: *substring()* is also all lowercase.  I've fixed it for you.  +1 for your *replace()* example, which is a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If your id always has "record" in front of it then...

```
$("a.removeTier").live('click', function() {
    var tier = $(this).attr('id').subString("6");
    alert(tier);
});
```

If you change the word "record" to something else just change the 6 the the position of the first number.